# Creating "current" links for nav in Liquid on Jekyll

Tags: html, css, ruby, jekyll, liquid

thanks for your time in advance. I've built a site based on the Jekyll tutorial site so it uses the same nav set up. I've modified it to have "current" links so I can style current page in the nav. It was working great at first but once I added my own CSS it broke something in Liquid. Here's the gist:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ item.link }}"
            {% if page.url == item.link %} 
                class="current"
            {% else %}
                class = "not-current"
            {% endif %}>{{ item.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

That's my navigation.html include, and here's my nav data:

```
- name: Home
  link: /
- name: About
  link: /about.html
```

This code successfully adds a 'current' class to my index page link in the nav, 'Home'. But when I go to about, in developer tools, the class is shown as 'not-current' when it should be current.

The Liquid given is running and working, since my 'Home'  tag gets the 'current' class, and that comes straight from the Liquid If/Else. When I click my 'About' link in the nav, both 'Home' and 'About' have 'not-current' as a class. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Site can be seen [here](https://samagurtam.github.io)

Comment: You can take a look at Jekyll's own navigation: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/docs/_includes/primary-nav-items.html

Comment: @DirtyF Good reference, but even that code fails to link my 'current' class to my About page <a> tag. It's something to do with Liquid since I can still go into dev tools, and manually add a 'current' class which styles it correctly. Tricky problem.

Comment: Solved this. Liquid's 'page.url' variable was pointing to '/about' and I was trying to compare '/about.html'. That .html is important apparently!